# How to read specific column index from csv using pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Is there some way of reading only a particular column with specific index from a csv file using Pandas(preferably read_csv)? I understand that read_csv provides the ability to read specific columns by column names, but the data file has no headers so I cannot use column names. Note that the file is too large, so I do not want to read in the entire file and then subset. Thanks.

Comment: `use_cols` supports ordinal based indexing: `use_cols=[1,4]` will read only 2nd and 5th column

Comment: Many thanks. It works.

Comment: Just a 'for information' - you can't combine index and name e.g. use_cols = ['Name', 5, 'Date' does *not* work]. It returns an error 'ValueError: 'usecols' must either be all strings, all unicode, all integers or a callable'.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example illustrating the answer given by EdChum. There is a lot of additional options to load a CSV file, check the [API reference](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

```
raw_data = {'first_name': ['Steve', 'Guido', 'John'],
        'last_name': ['Jobs', 'Van Rossum', "von Neumann"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
# Saving data without header
df.to_csv(path_or_buf='test.csv', header=False)
# Telling that there is no header and loading only the first name
df = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer='test.csv', header=None, usecols=[1], names=['first_name'])
df

  first_name
0      Steve
1      Guido
2       John
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('file.csv', usecols=['column_name'])
```

Parameter of `usecols` contain list of column name(s). If want more than one columns,then separate them by comma i.e., `['column_name1, 'column_name2', 'column_name3']`