# how to extract one specific column to a panda data frame from a text file with out coulmn headers

Tags: python, pandas

I created the single csv file -"dataaa.csv", entered column heading "operation"  to specify the column i want to extract, and used following code .

```
data = pd.read_csv('dataaa.csv')
df1=data.loc[:,"operation"]
```

.its working. but now i want to expand it to a real situation where,

I need to iterate the same procedure over 5210 file which is a result of split command in linux.The output file start with file name xxa. But it dosent contain   a column header "operation".How a can i read the column-which is the second column in my file, which is feasible enough to iterate over huge number of files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read specific column index from csv using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32441633/how-to-read-specific-column-index-from-csv-using-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `usecols` keyword from the read_csv function. See the full [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

```
data = pd.read_csv('dataaa.csv', usecols=[1], header=None)
```

> usecols : array-like or callable, default None
>
> Return a subset of the columns. If array-like, all elements must
>   either be positional (i.e. integer indices into the document columns)
>   or strings that correspond to column names provided either by the user
>   in names or inferred from the document header row(s). For example, a
>   valid array-like usecols parameter would be [0, 1, 2] or [‘foo’,
>   ‘bar’, ‘baz’].
>
> If callable, the callable function will be evaluated against the column names, returning names where the callable function evaluates to
>   True. An example of a valid callable argument would be lambda x:
>   x.upper() in ['AAA', 'BBB', 'DDD']. Using this parameter results in
>   much faster parsing time and lower memory usage.